# MultiThreading and LINQ and CPU usage

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, linq

I have selected data from database and fill my datatable.

Also I have 10 threads that select needed data from my datatable.

When these threads are started **concurrently**, the cpu usage goes up to 100%.

```
void TRD1_Task(DataTable myDataTable, Int64 thisCode)
    {
        DataTable dt1 = (from x in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                         where x.Field<Int64>("Code") == thisCode
                         select x).CopyToDataTable();
    }
```

What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to use the `ThreadPool` class instead of `Thread` class.

Comment: _What should I do?_  - start by asking an actual question. There's nothing wrong about 100% CPU, that's the purpose of threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using linq to sql

No, you're really not. Look here:

```
void TRD1_Task(DataTable myDataTable, Int64 thisCode)
```

That's not using LINQ to SQL. That's using a `DataTable`. That means you've already fetched *all* the data into your process. Don't do that.

If you were using LINQ to SQL, your query would be something like:

```
var query = from user in dbContext.Users
            where user.Code == thisCode
            select user;
```

You *may* have originally used LINQ to SQL to fetch the data for the `DataTable`, but if so then:

- It's odd to use `DataTable` at all, when presumably you've got a perfectly good strongly-typed model
- The fact that you're filtering *after* you've already fetched all the data makes it hideously inefficient - you want the filtering to be performed in the database itself.

The CPU problem is just a side-effect of the fact that you shouldn't have all this data in your process in the first place.